# CTFT of $ X(j\omega) $ vs $ X(jf) $

Tags: fourier-transform, continuous-signals

The CTFT of a signal as a function of $ \omega $ and $ f $ is identical:

$$ X(j\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(t) \, e^{-j \omega t} \operatorname{dt} \;\;\;\;\bigg|\;\;\;\; X(j f) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(t) \, e^{-j 2 \pi f t} \operatorname{dt} $$

But the Inverse CTFT has a scaling factor of $ 1 / (2 \pi) $ if $ f(t) $ is transformed from $ X(\omega) $:

$$ f(t) = {1 \over {2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} X(j\omega) \, e^{j \omega t} \operatorname{d\omega} \;\;\;\;\bigg|\;\;\;\; f(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} X(j f) \, e^{j 2 \pi f t} \operatorname{df} $$

**1. What is the conceptual implication of having the scaling factor?**

Say if if I have a signal that is a pure sinusoid ( $ 1V $ in voltage amplitude and $ 60 \operatorname{Hz} $ in frequency):

$$ x(t) = \cos(2\pi \cdot 60t) $$

The spectrums between $ X(j\omega) $ and $ X(jf) $ is practically identical

[image]

If I convert the $ X(\omega)$ and $ X(f) $ spectrum back into its time domain function $ f(t) $, I yield different results. I can reconstruct $ x(t) $ from $ X(jf) $ but there is this *(attenuating)* scaling factor of $ 1 / (2\pi) $ from $ X(j\omega) $:

$$ \begin{align} \text{from  }  X(\omega) \implies f(t) &= \frac{1}{2\pi} \big[ 0.5e^{j2\pi60t} + 0.5e^{-j2\pi60t}  \big] = \frac{1}{2\pi} \big[ 0.5\cos(2\pi60t) + 0.5\cos(2\pi60t) \big] \\ &= \frac{1}{2\pi} \cdot \cos(2 \pi 60t) \neq x(t) 
\\
&\implies 0.16V \text{ in voltage amplitude and frequency of } 60 \operatorname{Hz}
\end{align} $$

whereas,

$$ \begin{align} \text{from  }  X(f) \implies f(t) &= 0.5e^{j2\pi60t} + 0.5e^{-j2\pi60t} = 0.5\cos(2\pi60t) + 0.5\cos(2\pi60t) \\ &= \cos(2 \pi 60t) = x(t) \end{align} $$

**2. Does that imply that I have to normalized whichever value I read on a $ X(\omega) $ vs $ \omega $ plot by multiplying it by $ 2\pi $ or else the reconstructed voltage amplitude would be lower than what it really is?**

Comment: Reason for the downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $X(\omega)$ is incorrect. It should use

$$e^{j2\times\pi\times 60 t} \leftrightarrow 2\pi \delta(\omega-2\times\pi\times 60).$$ [See this table.](https://ethz.ch/content/dam/ethz/special-interest/baug/ibk/structural-mechanics-dam/education/identmeth/fourier.pdf)

[See this table for the same thing in $f$.](https://www.projectrhea.org/rhea/index.php/CT_Fourier_Transform_(frequency_in_hertz))

Comment: $ X(\omega) $ has two spectral lines each with amplitude 0.5. How do I write it in terms of $ 2\pi \delta(\omega-2\pi 60 $?  $$ X(\omega) = 0.5 \cdot 2\pi \delta(\omega -2\pi 60) \text{???} $$ But that would give me $$ 0.5 \cdot 2\pi \cdot 2 = 2\pi V $$ $ \approx $ six times the voltage magnitude of the original signal ($ 1V$)

Comment: @KMC Sorry! My bad. I updated my answer to use the correct Fourier transform pair. Yours will have a positive and negative frequency exponential with a coefficient of 0.5. So each will generate a term of $\pi\delta(\omega-2\times\pi\times 60)$.

Comment: I'm still not getting this ... so 
$$ x(t) = 0.5[\pi \delta(\omega-2 \pi 60)t] + 0.5[\pi \delta(-\omega-2\pi60)t]   $$ does not look like $$ x(t) = \cos(2\pi 60t) $$

Comment: @KMC But it is precisely that. That's what the Fourier transform tables I've posted say. $$0.5[2\pi \delta(\omega-2 \pi 60)] + 0.5[2\pi \delta(-\omega-2\pi60)]  \leftrightarrow \cos(2\pi 60t)$$.

Comment: I always thought (and I was taught that) the height of the spectral line in $ X(\omega) $ *IS* the value of the amplitude of the time-domain sinusoid of a corresponding $ \omega $, but it is wrong. So if I want to correlated the scalar value of the transformed function, I really need to normalize height by dividing the value by $ 2\pi $.  If I plot my spectral lines in $ X(\omega) $ I have two impulse each with height $ 0.5 \cdot 2\pi $. Whereas in $ X(f) $ their impulse height are exactly $ 0.5 $ which sum up to $ 1V $  for the sinusoid in the time domain.